# How to make a trigger fire correctly with a union of inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, union

I am trying to build a trigger for a table called B. The trigger will fire when rows are inserted into B, and decrement a column by one (called seats, that starts at 10) in another table(called F).

My problem is that I am forced to insert into B with a union of inserts, and the trigger only updates the relevant column in F once for each key, instead of for each row inserted.

My tables look like this

```
 B                                  F
------------------                 ------------------
CODE   DATE   id                   CODE  DATE  seats
```

so code and date is the relevant foreign key between the two tables.

An example of the insert statement I must follow is

```
    Insert into B;
    select 'JA100','11/30/16',81108 union
    select 'JA110','11/28/16',38003 union
    select 'JA110','11/28/16',87822 union
    select 'JA130','11/28/16',33850 union
    select 'JA100','11/30/16',69696 union
    select 'JA100','11/30/16',75657 union
```

The trigger I have written is

```
 BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE F 
        SET seats = seats - 1
        FROM F F, inserted I
        WHERE I.code = F.code AND I.date = F.date
    END
```

What I end up getting from this is 9 in the seats column for all three F's when it should be 7 for JA100, 8 for JA110, and 9 for JA130.

How do I fix this so it works? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You would have to aggregate seats per id/date and decrement the aggregate. As it stands the code will work only for Inserts where same key is present no more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to aggregate seats per id/date and decrement the aggregate from the table that tracks seat count.

Updated version of trigger below. Also see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bb0da/1 for working example.

```
create trigger insert_DecrementSeats on b
for insert
as
begin
    ;WITH seatsAggregated AS (
        SELECT [code], [date], COUNT(*) AS seats
        FROM
            inserted i
        GROUP BY [code], [date]
    ) UPDATE f
    SET f.seats = f.seats - a.seats
    FROM
        f
        INNER JOIN seatsAggregated a ON f.[code] = a.[code] AND f.[date] = a.[date]
end

go
```